# Enforce a 3 sec delay between login attempt to each visitor

Tags: php, html, mysql, security, brute-force

Is there a secure way (in php) to enforce a 3 second interval before a user can attempt to log in after a failed attempt? Not based on his ip or username (even if he tries to log in with non existent username), something like a global law.

Comment: I was thinking that if it is per username someone might "scam" someone he knows the username off and do many failed attempts ( and if the delay is scaling he would have to wait for long) and if it's per ip someone could use a different ip on each attempt or some other way

Comment: why not use a recaptcha

Comment: i tried that and i thought this is the way i'm fine now. But then i noticed that sometimes it works and sometimes it gives the following message: "Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again."

Answer (score 0):

You can create two columns in say `User` table. `is_failed_attempt` and `failed_attempt_timestamp`. Now, whenever user do a failed attempt, you update `is_failed_attempt` as `1` and update current time in `failed_attempt_timestamp`.

Now, put a check if `is_failed_attempt` = `1` and `failed_attempt_timestamp` < 5 seconds, prevent the user from log in.

Whenever, user do a successful login, update the `is_failed_attempt` to `0`.

Comment: What if the one attempting to log in is not a user?

Comment: If it's not a user, what's the point of enforcing 5 second interval? You'll probably greet them with `Invalid credentials` message.

Comment: I get that but can't the attacker that way actually find valid usernames since the interval will restrict him only when that happens?  Maybe it doesn't matter if he does since you will restrict him then but i was thinking that if there is a way as i described for all incoming attempts it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Write jQuery on submit event and store attempt number in COOKIE. check the number of attempt and disable submit button for 5 seconds using jQuery.

Comment: js can be disabled in browser you know. Putting security on the client side is a very bad idea

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most efficient way is to handle the security policy using a plugin on your web server.  If your PHP app is running under Apache, for example, you can look into the mod_security plugin.  It can address your stated concerns, as well as many security threats you might otherwise overlook.

https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual

Comment: Do you know any legit plugin for nginx?

Comment: @captainmonk Same plugin.  It works on Apache, Nginx, and IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can store `attempt_number` and `attempt_timestamp` in a session array. every time you need to check the `attempt_timestamp` and update it to the newest and increment `attempt_number` by `1` till the user fails to log in. When user successfully logged in, erase this session array.